# Is there any solution to appear table use tag <table> html in email intent android?

Tags: android, html

i have a problem to appear table using tag `<table>` html in email intent, this is my code :

```
    String[] TO = {""};
    String[] CC = {""};

    String msg= "<table border=1>" +
            "<th>WO</th>" +
            "<th>Item Number</th>" +
            "<th>Qty Open</th>" +
            "<th>UOM</th>" +
            "<th>Due Date</th>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>WO0001</td>" +
            "<td>FG001</td>" +
            "<td>100</td>" +
            "<td>EA</td>" +
            "<td>15-03-2016</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>WO0002</td>" +
            "<td>FG002</td>" +
            "<td>150</td>" +
            "<td>EA</td>" +
            "<td>25-03-2016</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>WO0005</td>" +
            "<td>FG002</td>" +
            "<td>100</td>" +
            "<td>EA</td>" +
            "<td>13-04-2016</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</table>"; 

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));        
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mType);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

the table cannot appear , i know that Html.fromHtml not support tag `<table>`. Is there  any solution to use `<table>` html in android email intent ?? thank you